# How to use entity designer of report bundle in my bundle

Tags: orocrm

i am working on my custom bundle but i am stuck on entity designer. i don't get how i can add fields in my page. like OROCrm -> Manage Custom Report -> add new report using designer tab

i want to use designer tab in my bundle but didn't get any help. please help me how i can use this designer on my page please following i have attached screenshot

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7ahYqdRrUEmU3BncXJlTGNqbHc/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if it's still relevant :) 
At least you can check

> Oro/Bundle/ReportBundle/Resources/views/Report/update.html.twig

to get an idea, note there's QD (query designer) macroses that you can re-use in your own templates.